# C++ Multiple constructor initialization and destruction

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have a class with two constructors:

```
A::A(int a) and A::A(double a).
```

These constructors initializes different member variables. In the first case I initialize a map and in the second case I initialize a pointer.

First case:

```
 A::A(int a): mymap() {}
```

Second case:

```
A::A(double a) : mypointer(NULL) {}
```

My question is that when two objects using these two different constructors are created, what should I consider when the destructor of this class is called? I mean is it enough to write the destructor as follows such that: 
- I check whether mymap is not empty then delete the entries
- I check whether  mypointer is not null then delete the mypointer.

```
A::~A(){
  if(!mymap.empty()) { delete entries and clear the map}

  if(mypointer != NULL) { delete mypointer; mypointer =NULL; } 
}
```

Then if I initialize both variables in both constructors like:

A::A(int a): mymap(), mypointer(NULL) {}
 A::A(double a) : mymap(), mypointer(NULL) {}

is my destructor safe? or should I remove if conditions and perform deletions directly.

Comment: both constructors should initialize all data members. Then there is no problem. And you don't have to check against `NULL` before deleting a pointer.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem: the class has two distinct contracts, one when initialized with an `int` and one when initialized with a `double`.

Comment: Depending on the contents of `mymap`, you might not have to do anything. Also, deleting a null pointer is okay and simply doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize all members in both constructors.

For example, think about the pointer you initialize in one of the constructors. Since the other constructor doesn't initialize it, then its value will be undefined and so you have undefined behavior when checking the pointer in the destructor.

Comment: If I initialize both variables in both constructors, how the above destructor should look like? Is it okay if I remove "if conditions" for mypointer and for the mymap in the destructor?

Comment: @AvbAvb If the map doesn't contain pointers then you don't need to do anything about it, as the maps destructor will properly destruct its data. And you can always do `delete` on a pointer even if it's `NULL` so no need to check that.

Comment: So then my check for the map is enough --> if(!mymap.empty()), right?.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize all members variables in constructor otherwise it leads to memory errors .
There is no need for check in case of `mymap` as mymap is not a pointer and in case of `mypointer` it is right to first check for `NULL`

Comment: Checking for `NULL` won't help if the pointer has not been initialized; it will have some random value that is not safe to delete.

Comment: And calling `delete` on a null pointer is a no-op. So it doesn't help to check.

Comment: If I initialize both variables in both constructors, how the above destructor should look like? Is it okay if I remove "if conditions" for mypointer and for the mymap in the destructor?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that when two objects using these two different constructors are created, what should I consider when the destructor of this class is called? I mean is it enough to write the destructor as follows such that: - I check whether mymap is not empty then delete the entries - I check whether mypointer is not null then delete the mypointer.

Your approach is technically correct - that is, check and release *all* resources in the destructor.
Conceptually, however, I'd recommend to have two classes as it looks you need at least *two* completeley different interfaces and implementations.